# Entityframework Core Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Int64'

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

DB first entity framework core throws this exception when SaveChanges();
This code works just fine with Entity Framework but not with Entity Framework Core.

> Exception message: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Int64'.

```
CsProduct csProduct = new CsProduct()
{
    CheapestPrice = 1,
    LastPrice = 1,
    LastUpdateDate = DateTime.Now,
    ProductName = "123",
    Quantity = 1,
    UploadDate = DateTime.Now
};
CSContext ctx = new CSContext();
ctx.Entry(csProduct).State = EntityState.Added; 
// ctx.CsProduct.Add(csProduct); This does not work neither
csProduct.ProductNo = 0; // Still throws exception without this line
ctx.SaveChanges();  

------------------------------------------------------------------ 
CsProduct.cs
public partial class CsProduct
{
    public CsProduct()
    {
    }

    public long ProductNo { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal CheapestPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal LastPrice { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DDL
CREATE TABLE CS_Product(
    productNo               bigint              IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL,
    productName             nvarchar(256)                   NOT NULL,
    cheapestPrice               decimal(14,2)                   NOT NULL,
    lastPrice                   decimal(14,2)                   NOT NULL,
    quantity                    int                         NOT NULL,
    uploadDate              datetime                        NOT NULL,
    lastUpdateDate          datetime                        NOT NULL,
    comment                 nvarchar(450)                           ,
    CONSTRAINT PK_CS_Product PRIMARY KEY (productNo),
);
```

Comment: Is there any fluent mapping code or migration code that incorrectly sets the type to `Int32`?

Comment: EF Core version: 1.1.0 and it should be mapped the primary key properly..because it was generated by entity framework using Scaffold-DbContext

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was my mistake..
When I first created the table, productNo was bigint and I created the model based on that table.
After that somehow (it must be me...) productNo changed to int.
It is working just fine after changing productNo back to bigint

Comment: you save my day

Comment: bigint  and bit. Some time we see same same. I have same issue with you.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason behind this line

```
csProduct.ProductNo = 0;
```

the framework will assign the key after save.

Just remove that line,  If you want the ID then after .SaveChanges();
then check the ID value of the Entity.

```
csRepository.CSContext.SaveChanges();
var NewID = csProduct.ProductNo;
```

Comment: just leave that line out.

Comment: FYI, that code works fine with entity framework, but not with entity framework core...

Comment: Not sure what you have in you repository but typically  I attach the new entity then set the state and then save.

Comment: There is really nothing in the repository. It just returns Context now. I did try also attaching the new entity first, but it still not working...I really cannot understand why it works with Entity framework but not with Entity framework core.